# C# asp.net why does my manual __doPostBack only run once?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my code I create the menu items dynamically:

```
string listClientID = BulletedList1.ClientID.Replace('_', '$');
int counter = 0;

foreach (DataRow dataRow in database.DataTable.Rows)
{
    // Add Button
    ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
    listItem.Value = "buttonItem" + Convert.ToString(dataRow["rank"]);
    listItem.Text = " " + Convert.ToString(dataRow["title"]);
    listItem.Attributes.Add("onclick", "__doPostBack('" + listClientID + "', '"+ counter.ToString() +"')");

    BulletedList1.Items.Add(listItem);

    counter++;

}
```

This menu is inside a update panel:

```
<div id="MenuItemBox">
    <asp:BulletedList 
        ID="BulletedList1" 
        runat="server"
        OnClick="MenuItem_Click"
        >
    </asp:BulletedList>
</div>
```

What I want is when a listitem is clicked it performs a postback. But when I run this, the onclick event is only runned once.

For example. I have 4 listitems. When I click the first item the first time the onclick event is executed. Now I click the second item, the onclick event is also executed. But when I now click the first item again the onclick event is not fired.

When I check the error console in FireFox or Oprah I don't get any errors.

So my question is: how can I fix this and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to rebind it after postback. 
Where do you add items to the menu and are you checking IsPostBack property?
Please compare html after first loading and postpack to see if _dopostback dissappear.

Then Try to remove IsPostBack check.
My code is working well.
Here is it.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e) { }

    protected override void OnInit (EventArgs e) {
        base.OnInit(e);
        //if (!IsPostBack) {
            string listClientID = BulletedList1.ClientID.Replace('_', '$');
            int counter = 0;

            List<SomeClass> items = new List<SomeClass>(){ new SomeClass() { Rank = 1, Title = "2"},
            new SomeClass () {Rank = 2, Title = "Two"}};


            foreach (var item in items) {
                // Add Button
                ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
                listItem.Value = "buttonItem" + item.Rank;
                listItem.Text = " " + item.Title;
                listItem.Attributes.Add("onclick", "__doPostBack('" + listClientID + "', '" + counter.ToString() + "')");

                BulletedList1.Items.Add(listItem);

                counter++;

            }
        //}
    }

    protected void MenuItem_Click (object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e) {
        Response.Write(e.Index);
    }

    class SomeClass {
        public int Rank;
        public string Title;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my page_load I have a check for isPostBack. If have something like if(!isPostBack){ build menu }. The __doPostBack doesn't disappear

Comment: Thnx for the answer but why do you use OnInit and not Page_Load?

Comment: I thought about ViewState. It is a difference where to assign values that will be saved in ViewState (in Init or in Load). So if it fixed your issue then we can study it in details. So is it fixed now?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. But yes, when I place this code in the OnInit() event the onlclick event stays working. But why place this code in the OnInit event and not in the Page_load() event?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry too. I had a lot of work. I just checked it again. I think the problem is in IsPostBack checking. It will work in Load event too if you delete IsPostBack checking. Haha I confused you about Init event, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Probably UpdatePanel is causing the trouble. I would try pulling it out of UpdatePanel and then would see(which I believe it should) if that works?

Secondly, you can probably just populate the list items Values and Texts only, and then under mnuMainMenu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e) event; look for the specific item that has been clicked (e.Item.* public properties), and then probably would use Response.Redirect() to do the job; well, just thinking out loud...

Comment: About the first thing you're right. That works. The second thing, I am doing that now. My bulletedlist contains an OnClick event. This method contains the following code: BulletedList1.Items[e.Index].Value;