# how to get the empid while click on a row of the repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater. i want to get empid when i click on its any row.? how can i ?
My code is:-

```
<table id="table1" class="yui" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a href='#' title="Click Header to Sort">Emp name #</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href='#' title="Click Header to Sort">emp sal</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href='#' title="Click Header to Sort">emp address</a>
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repaddressorbbl" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repaddressorbbl_ItemCommand">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr id="gh" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Select(this);">
                            <td style="text-align: center;">
                                <%#Eval("empname")%>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">
                                <%# Eval("empsal")%>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">
                                <%# Eval("empadd")%>
                            </td>
                               </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr id="pagerOne1">
                    <td colspan="4">
                        <img src="_assets/img/first.png" class="first" />
                        <img src="_assets/img/prev.png" class="prev" />
                        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay" />
                        <img src="_assets/img/next.png" class="next" />
                        <img src="_assets/img/last.png" class="last" />
                        <select class="pagesize">
                            <option selected="selected" value="100">100</option>
                            <option value="200">200</option>
                            <option value="400">400</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Comment: Do you want this on server-side postback or in JavaScript?

Comment: sir actually i want to bind another repeater using this id...

Comment: are you using jquery for binding your another repeater? have you checked my post??

Comment: Will come back to this if I have time...meanwhile you can refer some links and topics on how to manually do a postback.  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530511/c-sharp-asp-net-why-does-my-manual-dopostback-only-run-once>, <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference.aspx>, <http://weblogs.asp.net/mnolton/archive/2003/06/04/8260.aspx>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu have to create manual postback. But for this to work always, your repeater should bind always, i.e. during each postback.

The following code snippets may guide you.

```
using System;

namespace PostbackRef.Web
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                string arg = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg) == false)
                {
                    if (arg.StartsWith("row"))
                    {
                        string v = arg.Substring(arg.IndexOf("#") + 1);
                        txtSelected.Text = v;
                    }
                }
            }
            //Have to bind repeater always
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }

        protected string getPostbackReference(string Name)
        {
            return ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "rowEvent#" + Name);
        }
    }
}
```

The aspx markup looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="PostbackRef.Web._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        p
        {
            font-size: 12pt;
        }
        p:hover
        {
            background-color: Gray;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: White;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <p onclick="<%# getPostbackReference((string)Container.DataItem) %>">
                    <%# Container.DataItem %></p>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetNames"
            TypeName="PostbackRef.Web.MyDs"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfValue" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Clicked : 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSelected" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've used an ObjectDataSource which returns a string array of names, but the choice of datasource is entirely yours. Here I've used just for e.g. sake.

Note that I am calling Repeater1.Databind() on Page_Load irrespective of postback or not. There are probably better ways to do this. But most of the code came exactly [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/mnolton/archive/2003/06/04/8260.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here the sample with checkbox control. Same way you gonna use with button or any click events. Make it one hidden for empid.

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
CheckBox box = sender as CheckBox;

RepeaterItem item = box.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
HiddenField hf = item.FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;string id = hf.Value;

}



<ItemTemplate>

<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" />

</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I just give a sample ok no need checkbox. Any server control give click event and get using hidden field. Now you give cilck event in TR but its not enable Runat="server". Are you want to work with JS Or Server side?

Comment: with any kind i just want to get id. and one thing more after this i have to bind other grid...

Answer (score 0):

a quick write -up

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repaddressorbbl" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repaddressorbbl_ItemCommand">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr id="gh" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Select('<%# Eval("EmployeeID")%>');">
                            <td style="text-align: center;">
                                <%#Eval("empname")%>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">
                                <%# Eval("empsal")%>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">
                                <%# Eval("empadd")%>
                            </td>
                               </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

try this one